# How can i activate/enable contextmenustrip menu only if the listView is not empty?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is what i'm doing in the constructor:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item1.Name = "Open File Folder Location";
item1.Text = "Open File Folder Location";
item1.Click += contextMenuStrip1_ItemClick;
ToolStripMenuItem item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item2.Name = "Launch File";
item2.Text = "Launch File";
item2.Click += contextMenuStrip2_ItemClick;
ToolStripMenuItem item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item3.Name = "Copy File";
item3.Text = "Copy File";
item3.Click += contextMenuStrip3_ItemClick;
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item1);
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item2);
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item3);
```

But even if the listView lvnf is empty it will show the menu on right click.
I want that only if ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count is bigger then 0 to enable the menu.

And since in the program the listView might be get empty too not only when running the program i need to check it also while the program is running and not only once a the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the "Opening" event of ContextMenuStrip.
If you shortly double click on the contextMenuStrip1, a function will created in code file and binded to Opening event.

Setting CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to true will prevent the menu from opening.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{    
   var listView = (ListView)contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl;
   if (listView.Items.Count == 0)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```